# Designing a "renderer", is there a point to use an API other than OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, directx

I've been thinking, perhaps for too long. At the moment, I have an abstract base class called "Renderer", it has virtual methods to render and register objects (I have to register objects to allocate memory for VBO's).

However, I'm not sure if I should keep it like that, I'm thinking I should keep the base abstract class. I just wouldn't create another "Renderer" that will render my objects with another API, other than OpenGL. So in other words, I won't use Direct3D or any other graphics API except for OpenGL.

But I may have multiple implementations of the OpenGL renderer, for example one for OpenGL ES and normal OpenGL (if they vary that much, that is).

If I were to use another API, such as Direct3D, creating the context would probably be the main concern for me... I'm just not sure how I would do it in a neat way.

Sorry if this doesn't make any sense, I think I've been thinking for way too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leveraging 3D APIs is no easy task; I'm still working towards that end for myself, although the OpenGL support remains mostly missing and the API therefore highly theoretical, at least until I reach a decent milestone with the Direct3D implementation, and find some decent docs on OpenGL so I can try to build up the OpenGL variant to see how far I get, and how many of my assumptions actually comply with reality.

That will probably be the time when I either get really surprised about being such a genius when I see that implementing OpenGL is just a breeze with the existing design --- or (more likely) when I decide to drop OpenGL (and MacOS+Linux along with it) completely :-)

I can do that because it's a private pet project that won't ever get finished anyway. For anything that has a remote chance of getting done, or something that needs to get done, I would recommend to not do it. It's a lot of work.

things you have to do, at least, include:

- making your API abstract enough so there's no application-visible difference between the two rendering APIs while not loosing performance (so don't do things by converting things around all the time. It's nice to have a million vertices in some abstract data collection and converting that to Direct3D or OpenGL every time for maximum flexibility, but that will just give you a slideshow. Thus, in my opinion, the way to go is for the rendering API to actually work with higher level data such as models or scenarios instead of vertices and triangles)

Of course, a major problem for me is that I'm not just trying to get Direct3D and OpenGL abstracted away without loosing performance, I'm also trying to build up 3D-gfx-know-how along the way. Which makes it difficult to come up with the "best" design, and needs a lot of going back.

- decide on how you deal with shaders (currently, I decided to not deal with those at all, and just require applications to provide both implementations). My main hope currently rests on the shaders -- the assumption being that once I get all the technical details and API specific stuff wrapped up, 3D-graphics in 2012 should be mostly a matter of running shaders on data and buffers.

Of course I might be all wrong and Direct3D/OpenGL are really the same thing that could be dealt with via 1:1 mappings using macros, but I'm positive it's not THAT simple. It still works on the same hardware with a fixed set of capabilities, and I even believe that HLSL and GLSL are similar enough to eventually make a single unified language for both.

Still, the reason why I'm writing all that rambling here is to discourage you. As far as *I* can tell (and guess what, you probably never ever heard my name -- make your own guess what that means) it's quite a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do. Why do you want to support both APIs? If you don't have a very compelling reason I would stick with D3D for Windows and OpenGL for Linux.

What you are trying to do can be done using an abstract base class that defines the interface of the renderer and then two different implementations one for OpenGL and one for Direct3D, but it involves virtual function calls for all your rendering calls which is going to add overhead.

I added two links that discusses this topic. If you don't have to support multiple APIs just stick with the one that is right for the platform you are targetting.

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/160063-support-for-both-opengl-and-directx/

http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/striving-for-graphics-api-independence-r1672

Answer (score 0):

My question is always "would it make sense to replace this implementation with an alternative, even if I don't want to do it now".

For something like a string, or a vector, or a class representing a player in a game the answer is probably no. You might change the implementation but you'd never need more than one. For something like a render system the answer is yes. It does make sense to replace this with a diferent implementation, therefore programming to an abstraction is a good idea even if you never will.

Of couse don't apply the rule blindly, efficiency and lack of clutter in the source code is important too, but I find it a good guideline.

Having said this, I wouldn't try to abstract the low level rendering stuff, it's just too hard. How would you provide a useable abstraction of tesselation hardware on a render system that simply doesn't have that ability? Instead I would make my abstraction at the level of "draw a landscape", "draw a 3 model", "drawn animated model" etc.

You may never implement a second system, but it makes sense to do so, so provide the abstraction unless there is a positive reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this is very useful. Since you are abstracting away this part, it makes no difference to the library user whether the underlying API is Direct3D or OpenGL. They are functionally identical, both do the exact same thing. They are using different proramming models and are based on different design/marketing stragegies, but none of them is fundamentally superior to the other in any way.
There are frequent battles between fanboys of both APIs, but the simple truth is that they do the same.

That said, one reason why one would want to support different backends is portability. OpenGL, with the exception of context creation and some minor details (such as switching vertical sync on and off), is already portable without needing anything special. Direct3D runs under Windows and XBox, and that is pretty much it.

I wouldn't myself consider making an OpenGL ES backend in addition to OpenGL either, because it quite possibly is enough of a different beast to make your life unhappy. But of course it very much depends on what you intend to do.
For "simple" things, OpenGL ES is in some way "just OpenGL" that runs on your mobile phone, too. Great, isn't it? Sounds too good to be true.
For "not so simple things", OpenGL ES turns out to always lack exactly the one feature that you're using for some effect (it did for me, anyway, eventually I dropped it) and causes great headaches finding a gentle way of downgrading.